# Moving unstaged + uncommitted changes between Mercurial branches

Tags: mercurial, branch, dvcs

I cloned a Mercurial repo and did a bunch of local work, and *forgot* to make a feature branch for said work.

The normal flow is:

1. Clone
2. Create a branch
3. Switch to that branch
4. Do your work in that branch
5. Push that branch
6. Code review
7. If code review passes, merge branch w/ `default` (locally)
8. Push merged changes to `default`
9. Close the feature branch

So I need to create a new branch, port all my unstaged/uncommitted code changes (made to `default`) over to this branch (so that `default` is now clean and the new branch contains my changes), and then push my feature branch.

I created the new branch via `hg branch new_feature`. But after pouring over the Merucrial docs, I can't figure out the next step.

So I ask: **How do I move (not just copy) all my unstaged/uncommitted changes from `default` to my `new_feature` branch)?**

Comment: Can't you just set the branch name and then commit? `hg branch feature-X` followed by the normal `hg commit -m "added feature X"` ?

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen (+1) - I guess I don't know... does `hg branch` clone `default` as it currently looks (which would include my changes), or does it clone `default` based on how it looked when I originally cloned the repo?

Comment: It does neither, it just records what branch name you would like to commit to. Nothing is changed in your working folder.

Comment: If you inspect the `.hg` folder there should be a file there named `branch`, this is a text file containing the name of the branch you're currently on. If you execute `hg branch X` the contents of this file will be `X`, and then when you commit you will commit a new changeset to branch X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything in particular.

Your uncommitted working folder changes are fluid, and you can set the branch name before you commit, without losing your changes.

If you're on the command line, simply do this:

```
hg branch feature-X
hg commit -m "Added feature X"
```

If you're using TortoiseHg simply click the "Branch: default" button just above the commit message input field and select "Open a new named branch" and give it a name, then click OK, then commit as normal.

Setting the branch name to use during commit does not in fact change your working folder, it doesn't do an update, it doesn't do anything, except record in metadata what the branch name is supposed to be.

Also note that this will only allow you to create a new branch to commit to. If you want to *continue* on an existing branch you first need to update to the head of that branch and this may cause changes to your working folder. You should not need to do this, however, if you want to create a new branch.

Comment: Thanks @Lasse V. Karlsen (+1) - do you mind addressing my one concern above (under your comment)? Thanks again!

Comment: There is nothing to be worried about in this regard, as executing `hg branch X` will simply record that *the next commit should be on branch X*.

Comment: Mind though, that a branch might not be the best thing to do for just creating a single feature. Maybe a bookmark is the better option in this case than a branch which will occupy its name forever, even after it has been merged back into default?